# How to create local for remote branch and push changes to remote using GIT

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-push, git-pull

I have a master branch. I created a local-feature-branch from master and pushed changes to remote-feature-branch.

After pushing this, someone my local-feature-branch was lost. Now, how do i re-use the latest changes from the remote-feature-branch and create the same local-feautre-branch. Before re-using the latest changes from remote-feature-branch, i need to get latest from master and push it to -remote-feature-branch

Once created, if i make any changes to the local-feature-branch, how do i push this to remote-feature-branch.

This is a little confusing. can someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand Your problem correctly, but my understanding is that You want to use the remote feature branch and merge it with master.

Let's name the feature branch `feature-branch` for the purpose of simplicity. I assume here that Your remote repository is named `origin`.

What You can do is:

```
git checkout origin/feature-branch
git rebase master
git push origin feature-branch --force
```

Alternatively, instead of `rebase` You can use `merge` to merge the master to Your branch.

Comment: Wosinski- i m trying to create a local-branch from the origin/feature-branch. so that i can work on that feature-branch. Once my work is done, i need to push back to the origin/feature-branch

Comment: Yeah, that is what I have described :) You checkout the branch to crate a local branch, then merge/rebase on master, as You wanted and then push the branch to the origin.